# Error with Clousure in zend framework cache

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I have problem with Zend Framework cache - this error shows when I put my app on production.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state() in /home/users/devmonitoring/data/cache/module-config-cache.application.config.cache.php:67 

Stack trace: 
#0 /home/users/devmonitoring/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ConfigListener.php(392): include() 
#1 /home/users/devmonitoring/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ConfigListener.php(70): Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener->getCachedConfig() 
#2 /home/users/devmonitoring/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/DefaultListenerAggregate.php(98): Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener->__construct(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ListenerOptions)) 
#3 /home/users/devmonitoring/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/DefaultListenerAggregate.php(42): Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\DefaultListenerAggregate->getConfigListener() 
#4 /home/users/devmonitoring/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ModuleManagerFactory.php(77): Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\DefaultListenerAggregate-> in /home/users/devmonitoring/data/cache/module-config-cache.application.config.cache.php on line 67
```

I try to clear cache, but this error still happens.

Comment: Do you have a closure in your module config somewhere?

Comment: Yes, sometimes instead of factory I'm using closures? Is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time you turn caching on for you config files, you set PHP up to a task it cannot do, i.e. closure serialization. It simply can't.

> Additionally you will lose the ability to use the caching feature of
>   the configuration files when you use closures within them. This is a
>   limitation of PHP which can’t (de)serialize closures.

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html

In other words you have to recourse to factories.